# How to read Telnet input stream with SocketChannel and ByteBuffer

Tags: java, sockets, nio, telnet, bytebuffer

I am trying to read some telnet input stream using SocketChannel and ByteBuffer.

So, to do this I made to threads, one to read data, and other one to send(write) some data.

In readResponse() I cant get the exactly number of bytes that I have to read from the stream, so when I enter in this method. I read some data with read() then it leaves while loop and control variable changes to true, so the other thread to send some data is called.

How can I read **all** the data from InputStream ?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MessageResponse {

    static Telnet telnet;

    public MessageResponse() throws IOException {
        telnet = new Telnet();
        new Producer().start();
        new Consumer().start();
    }

    class Producer extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    telnet.sendMessage();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MessageResponse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Consumer extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    telnet.readReponse();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MessageResponse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Telnet {
        //Socket s;
        String host = "";
        int port = 23;
        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        InputStream in = null;
        BufferedReader s_in = null;
        PrintWriter s_out = null;
        StringBuffer sb;
        Scanner scan;
        boolean control= false;
        SocketChannel channel;
        ByteBuffer buffer;
        Charset charset;

        public Telnet() throws IOException {
            channel = SocketChannel.open(address);
            channel.configureBlocking(false);
            buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
            charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            sb = new StringBuffer();
        }

        synchronized void readReponse() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            while (control== false) {
                channel.read(buffer);
                buffer.flip();
                System.out.println("Contets of Telnet ");
                while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                    System.out.print((char) buffer.get());
                    sb.append((char) buffer.get());
                }
                System.out.println(sb);
                control= true;
                notify();
            }
            while (control == true) {
                wait();
            }
        }

        synchronized void sendMessage() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            while (control==true){  
            System.out.println("Enter command: ");
            String comando = scan.nextLine();
            channel.write(charset.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(comando)));
            control= false;
            notify();
            }
            while (control==false) {
                wait();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MessageResponse mr = new MessageResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters you may want to have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html); secondly, your lock scenario is, uh... Complicated would only start to describe it

Comment: Why my lock scenario is complicated ? Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: If you have two threads there is no reason to be using non-blocking mode at all. NIO in a client doesn't make much sense anyway. Switch to Socket, InputStream, and OutputStream.

Comment: EJP, I tried to use blocking mode, but couldnt think how to notify the "sendMessage" method that the reading data thread has been blocked. Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: You would need to explain why. I've written many Telnet clients without ever needing that.

Comment: EJP I used the ready() method of BufferedReader to do the loop that reads all the data from the InputStream. Thanks for helping me !